# Python - exec define member function of a class from an string

Tags: python

I am new to Python and developing a custom CLI, which would allow user to define functions dynamically on the CLI(Custom CLI module derived from cmd.Cmd module). Overriden default() method in custom command module will take the string entered by user and has to exec the code, be it dynamic function definition or other custom task. 
i.e My requirement is to convert the below CLI code dynamically to a member function, so that user can execute the function from the Cli object

```
  CLI:>def abc(self):print("New fn")
  CLI:>print(cli.abc()) # Cli object pre-created
  Output: New fn
```

default method would get the string entered from CLI as args.

```
  class CliCmd(cmd.Cmd):
         def default(self, func): # func = "def abc(self):print("New fn")"
             # Parse for function name
             funcName = func.split()[1].split("(")[0]
             exec(func) 
             setattr(self.__class__, funcName, ?) # How do I feed the function object
```

Where in older python, I can do exec func.strip() in dict, exec returns only None in Python 3.2. So, I am not sure how to get the function object for abc(), which I could in-turn bind with the class using setattr. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is in the global namespace, you can do this:

```
setattr(self.__class__, funcName, globals()[funcName])
```

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#globals